# pg_dump doesn't work in php, but working in .bat file

Tags: php, batch-file, exec

I made some .bat program that making backup of my database.
When i open cmd and run bat file through command line everything working fine.
But I also need php file to execute that .bat file.
I have very simple program with only one line of code

```
system("cmd /C backup.bat");
```

And now I have a problem, because when I execute this .php file backup have always 0 kb.

Comment: Does Apache (assuming your using apache) have permissions to run the `system()` function?.

Comment: Ok now working from command line, but when I trying to run this php file from browser it is not working.

Comment: when you run commands like system, shell_exec etc. the user has no env  environment, i.e. all path settings and others settings are not available. Furthermore it may well be that this user may not execute the command as it is now run as the webserver's user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

1. In widows open Postgresql
2. Open pg_hba.conf
3. Add line host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust

Of course you can modify your IP addres, mask etc. 
The most important thing is `trust` on the end of the line